# how to retrieve the id of the album profile facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, photo

I seek how to retrieve the id of the profile album facebook
I found this code

```
$albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");

foreach($albums["data"] as $item){
    echo $item["type"]." *********** ".$item["id"]."<br />";
    /if($item["type"] == "profile"){
        $album_id = $item["id"];
        break;
    }

}
```

but unfortunately he only shows 25 album and if the user has more than 25 album you can not recover its id of the profile photo abum
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the limit parameter to a higher value – `$facebook->api("/me/albums?limit=500");`

And if that doesn’t help, there should be prev/next-URLs in the response your getting, so you have to follow those.